# Cancel Delayed Chained PayPal Payment

Tags: paypal, delay, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained

I am using Delayed Chained PayPal Payment  It's working fine, but I want option to cancel payment within a time period. Can you please let me know how can I cancel payment within a period?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am still finding api for cancel payment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a cancel payment call but you don't need it.
When the payment is approved by the sender you can call [refund](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/) to revert it or [execute](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ExecutePayment_API_Operation/) to send money to secondary receiver(s). Before the sender approves the payment you don't need to cancel it just let it expire. You can control expiration by setting payKeyDuration on the [pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) call.